# Qt Validator Regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm trying to validate entry into a QLineEdit and I have my syntax wrong somewhere because when I run my program it doesn't allow me to enter anything in the edit box. The entry needs to be 3 uppercase alphabetic characters, followed by 1,2 or 3, and then a further 2 digits and then one final character alphabetic or digit.

```
QRegExp StudentForm::modCodeFormat("(\\s{3}\\d[123]\\d{2}\\w{1})");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(\\s{3}\\d[123]\\d{2}\\w{1})
   ^      ^       ^     ^
  This mat|ches wh|ite s|pace characters, not uppercase alphabetics
          |       |     |
        This match|es a |number then either a 1, 2 or a 3
                  |     |
                This mat|ches two numbers
                        |
                   This matches a single word characters, that is either a single number, uppercase, lowercase or an underscore _ character
```

Instead you should use:

```
^[A-Z]{3}[123][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```